# Grails database migration changelog woes

Tags: grails, database-migration

I'm struggling to follow [this](http://blog.springsource.org/2011/08/17/countdown-to-grails-2-0-database-migrations/) tutorial.  Here are the steps I have taken:

**1.)** I first create my empty changelog.  Before I run this command I set my development `dbCreate` to `create`.

`grails dbm-create-changelog`

**2.)** Then I generate the initial gorm changelog.  The tutorial says I should use the `prod` flag, but since my production database is empty I drop the `prod` flag.  Before I run this command I comment out my development `dbCreate` setting.

`grails dbm-generate-gorm-changelog --add changelog-1.0.groovy`

At this point my `migrations` folder contains the files `changelog.groovy` and `changelog-1.0.groovy`.  I will refer to `changelog-1.0.groovy` as `changelog #1`

**3.)** I now attempt to initialize my production database with the changelog I just created.  I set the database migration `updateOnStart` and `updateOnStartFileNames` in my config as indicated in the tutorial I linked to.  My production database exists, but is empty (no tables).  The `dbCreate` setting for my production environment has been commented out.

`grails prod run-app`

**THE PROBLEM:**

At first glance this appears to have worked, but **when I run `grails prod dbm-gorm-diff` and generate `changelog #2` I see changes that should not exist.  I can also see that the changesets are legit when compared to the production database's current state.  This means the production database was not initialized correctly with `changelog #1`.**  No changes should exist since I changed nothing.  I ran `grails prod dbm-gorm-diff` immediately after I ran `grails prod run-app`.

There are five changesets in the `changelog #2`.  I have verified that all of these changesets are represented in the `changelog #1`.  The first four changeset in `changelog #2` all have `unique: "true"`.  These four changesets are also the only changesets to contain `unique: "true"` in `changelog #1`.  I am still at a loss to explain why the fifth changeset exists.  There is nothing remarkable about it that I can see, though it is for the `user_role` table used by the [Spring Security plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core/).  Here is `changelog #2`:

```
databaseChangeLog = {

    changeSet(author: "typoknig (generated)", id: "1341970550063-1") {
        createIndex(indexName: "authority_unique_1341970549765", tableName: "role", unique: "true") { // This table is for the Spring Security plugin's "Role" domain class.
            column(name: "authority")
        }
    }

    changeSet(author: "typoknig (generated)", id: "1341970550063-2") {
        createIndex(indexName: "name_unique_1341970549772", tableName: "foo", unique: "true") { // This is just a table for one of my domain classes that happens to have a field with a unique constraint.
            column(name: "path")
        }
    }

    changeSet(author: "typoknig (generated)", id: "1341970550063-3") {
        createIndex(indexName: "name_unique_1341970549774", tableName: "bar", unique: "true") { // This is just a table for one of my domain classes that happens to have a field with a unique constraint.
            column(name: "name")
        }
    }

    changeSet(author: "typoknig (generated)", id: "1341970550063-4") {
        createIndex(indexName: "username_unique_1341970549777", tableName: "user", unique: "true") { // This table is for the Spring Security plugin's "User" domain class.
            column(name: "username")
        }
    }

    changeSet(author: "typoknig (generated)", id: "1341970550063-5") {
        createIndex(indexName: "FK143BF46A5FBC0B79", tableName: "user_role") { // This table is for the Spring Security plugin's "UserRole" domain class.
            column(name: "role_id")
        }
    }
}
```

**What do I need to do to make sure my production database is initialized correctly?**

**UPDATE #1:**

I don't know why, but `createIndex` isn't working with `unique: "true"`.  For the first four changesets I simply moved `unique: "true"` to the location where the column in question was originally being created in `changeset #1`.  This leaves only the fifth changeset in `changelog #2` to take care of.  I still don't see any issues with the changeset, so I don't understand why it is not being applied.

**UPDATE #2:**

I found that I can move all the calls to `createIndex` out of the individual changesets into the corresponding changeset where the table (which the index belongs to) was created.  **This seems to have solved all my issues.**  Unless someone can provide a compelling reason not to, I think I will make this part of my changelog generation work flow.  For example these changesets:

```
changeSet(author: "typoknig (generated)", id: "1342037835503-31") {
    createTable(tableName: "user_role") {
        column(name: "role_id", type: "bigint") {
            constraints(nullable: "false")
        }

        column(name: "user_id", type: "bigint") {
            constraints(nullable: "false")
        }
    }
}

changeSet(author: "typoknig (generated)", id: "1342037835503-103") {
    createIndex(indexName: "FK143BF46A4E6CF59", tableName: "user_role") {
        column(name: "user_id")
    }
}

changeSet(author: "typoknig (generated)", id: "1342037835503-104") {
    createIndex(indexName: "FK143BF46A5FBC0B79", tableName: "user_role") {
        column(name: "role_id")
    }
}
```

Would be come this changeset:

```
changeSet(author: "typoknig (generated)", id: "1342037835503-31") {
    createTable(tableName: "user_role") {
        column(name: "role_id", type: "bigint") {
            constraints(nullable: "false")
        }

        column(name: "user_id", type: "bigint") {
            constraints(nullable: "false")
        }
    }
    createIndex(indexName: "FK143BF46A5FBC0B79", tableName: "user_role") {
        column(name: "role_id")
    }
    createIndex(indexName: "FK143BF46A4E6CF59", tableName: "user_role") {
        column(name: "user_id")
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried not relying on the `updateOnStart` functionality but instead running the update script directly?

Comment: You are nearly always going to get changes when running the diff.  Diff is imperfect and it should be used as a suggestion.  I always get createIndex changeSets when I do a diff.  I just delete them and keep/tweak what I need.

Comment: @Gregg If the diff showed me changes that had already been applied to my DB I would be annoyed, but not horribly concerned. That is not the case though. The diff is accurate because `changelog #1` was not correctly applied to my production DB. The production DB was initialized from a changelog created from the development DB so even if there are "differences" the DBs should be identical. Again this is not the case. For example, regarding the first changeset in `changelog #2`, the development DB has a `unique` constraint on the `authority` column in the `role` table, the production DB does not.

Comment: @cdeszaq I have not tried that yet. I'll give it a go and report back.

Comment: @Gregg - That's exactly what I do too. Both to catch things that the diff missed or can't do via the built-in operations, or to simply clean up the changes so they are not so verbose.

Comment: @cdeszaq I tried to run `dbm-update` on my production DB but apparently that command will not work if your database is empty (no tables). I would like to go from empty to current GORM state as the tutorial suggests to do.

Answer (score 0):

Changesets can be dependent on the target database. For example, the grails.org site used to use MyISAM tables with MySQL and `dbm-gorm-diff` would always add some `createIndex` changesets, even if they were defined in previous changesets.

I really don't see how moving the `createIndex` declarations into the `createTable` changesets  would make any difference. Can you clarify how doing so has fixed all your problems?

Comment: Peter, I don't see how moving the `createIndex` declarations into the `createTable` changesets would make a difference either, but it does.  I can offer no clarification on why it is working, though I wish I could.